# SwiftUI nested API JSON call

Tags: swift, api, rest, swiftui

I'm working on a little SwiftUI Project with some data, hosted by my own local network.

When the view appears, I'm calling the `QuestionApiCall().getAllQuestions` method which returns an Array of Question Objects. So far so good.
In every Question Object inside of the returned Array, there is a variable called senderId.
This variable is necessary for calling another Method: `UserByApiCall(id: senderId).getUserById` for getting the name of the User which asked the Question.

My idea was:

```
ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
    VStack {
       ForEach(questions) {question in
           QuestionView(name: ?, content: question.content, creationTime: question.creation)
       }
    }
}
.onAppear() {
    QuestionApiCall().getAllQuestions { (questions) in
        self.questions = questions
}
```

Displaying the Question works properly but I don't know how to display their names, which can only displayed when calling the `UserByApiCall(id: senderId).getUserById` every time it loops threw the questions-Array with the specific senderId.

In theory I need to execute the `UserByApiCall(id: senderId).getUserById` every time question gets looped in the ForEach-Loop with the `question.senderId` for getting the User Object for every Question to display their names.

I really got no Idea how to make it or where to call it.
I can't just edit the Api and their methods because its an exercise from my Internship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really can´t change the API move the responsibility to call the name API to your `QuestionView`.

As you didn´t include your `QuestionView` I need to make a few asumptions about it.

Your `name` var should look like this:

```
@State private var name: String = ""
```

In the `.onApear` of `QuestionView` add your function to call the name:

```
.onApear{
    if name == ""{
        UserByApiCall(id: senderId).getUserById{[weak self] name in
            self?.name = name
        }
    }
}
```

And finally make your `VStack` a `LazyVStack`:

```
LazyVStack {
   ForEach(questions) {question in
       QuestionView(name: ?, content: question.content, creationTime: question.creation)
   }
}
```

The `LazyVstack` will ensure, that not all elements are loaded at once.